# How can Interactive Grid region be refreshed when region display selector changes in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have three regions named **Order Taken, Order Process and order Completed**. Each of the regions are based on Interactive Grid and each regions set to on as region display selector.

Now, when I updated order-status of 481 order-no to taken-order-status(0) in order process region, then i want to show the changes occur in taken-order region.

More simply, I just wants refreshed data every-time only when i changes/switches region or changes region display selector.

[image: Order Taken]
[image: Order Process]

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be to hide the Save buttons on the individual Interactive Grids (IGs) and instead have a page button called Save that submits the page.  This will cause all IGs to be processed and the page to be reloaded, so all IGs will be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding dynamic actions on region display selector? You can refresh the region when that region is clicked on the region display selector.

1. Create a dynamic action on region display sector - on click event on the region. One dynamic action for each region.
2. Create a refresh action under true. and select the same region to refreshed as one clicked.

Does that help your case?

Comment: NO.. I HAVE TRIED.. I THINK THAT IT NEEDS TO INVOKE THE EVENTS BY JAVASCRIPT CODING WITH THE HELP OF INSPECT ELEMENT OR NEED CLIENT SIDE JAVASCRIPT EXECUTION.. BUT DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO.

Comment: Caps lock stuck? ;-)

Comment: How exactly have you tried? I have done this earlier, (perhaps combined with dynamic actions with jquery selectors) work just fine. I cant provide you step by step instructions at the moment. But it might be good if you show how you did it.

Comment: Yes use a JQuery selector if you are going to do it this way, or JS.

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code in the Function and Global Variable Decleration Section

```
$('.apex-rds').data('onRegionChange', function(mode,activeTab) { 
                if ((activeTab.href === "#REGION_STATIC_ID")){ 
                    apex.region(activeTab.href.replace("#","")).refresh(); 
                }            
        });
```

NOTE: Replace **REGION_STATIC_ID** with the static id of your region.